# Por que mi ventana de python se cierra kuego de un milisegundo?

Tags: pygame

Tengo una ventana , generada con python , pygame ,para la creacion de un juego, por el momento solo tengo una ventana que pinto, pero se me cierra al momento , no se logra visualizar nada. Este es mi codigo:

```
pygame.init()

width = 400
height = 500

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))  #Surface
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 315)
rect = pygame.Rect(100, 150, 120, 60)
rect.center = (width//2 ,height//2)
white = (255, 255, 255)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
surface.fill(white)
pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, rect)
pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

el problema se encuentra en tu bucle en la identacion. surface.fill(white) y lo de mas fuera de tu for se encuentra fuera de tu bucle. entonces el codigo ya termina y por eso se cierra la ventana. la solucion es meter el resto del codigo a tu bucle a si:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    surface.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, red, rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

lamento no poder explicartelo mejor